# Putting out fires means to put out the fires. But what if it's a just a spark or at the kindling stage, and you put it out, is there a word for that?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that is about stifling a spark, not yet a fire. Is there a word for that?

Comment: Try *extinguish*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**douse** 1. TRANSITIVE VERB
If you douse a fire, you stop it from burning by pouring a lot of water over it.
The pumps were started and the crew began to douse the fire with water.
2. TRANSITIVE VERB
If you douse someone or something with a liquid, you throw a lot of that liquid over them.
They hurled abuse at their victim as they doused him with gasoline. [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/douse)

**quench**
transitive verb
1a: PUT OUT, EXTINGUISH
b: to put out the light or fire of
*quench* glowing coals with water.
[m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quench)

You can *extinguish* a small  fire with a fire extinguisher, for example. The fire department extinguish larger one. Douse, to my mind, is apt for small fires -- perhaps a pan catches fire while cooking. It connotes the use of a quantity of water. You can douse a campfire with water. It can be used for large fires as well, however.

Instead of water, you can use a lid or a towel *to smother* a kitchen fire.

**smother**
verb (used with object)
to stifle or suffocate, as by smoke or other means of preventing free breathing.
to extinguish or deaden (fire, coals, etc.) by covering so as to exclude air. [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/smothering)

Getting smaller, some folks like to show off and *snuff out* a candle using their fingers; others simply *blow* a candle *out*. You can *put out* a fire as well. The phrasal verb, as you might expect, is less formal than *extinguish*, which we get from Latin.

"Humans cause nearly 85 percent of wildland fires in the United States, according to the Forest Service. One of the culprits? Campfires that aren’t completely out. Letting your post-s’mores logs burn down unsupervised isn’t safe—you’ve got to **douse** them with water until the coals are cool."
[The Right Way to Put Out Your Campfire](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/571348/edit)

"If you need to add water to **douse** any embers, do so slowly, and sprinkle it on rather than soaking the fire and surrounding soil."
*[Camping for Dummies](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Camping_For_Dummies/iHhXTAzlufEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=douse%20embers&pg=PT247&printsec=frontcover)*

Comment: It's easier to rate an answer when it is *an answer* rather than a selection of choices.

Comment: Metaphorically, you can strangle the baby in its crib.

Comment: It's hard to choose one answer when you don't know if the fire is a spark, an ember, a match, a candle, or some burning twigs. You don't blow out an ember.

Comment: Add *snuff*....

Comment: It’s included in the answer. I think this is a good answer to a reasonable question.

Comment: Many phrasal verbs with completive _out_ or _off_ particles will work, depending on the verb -- _pinch out a match, rub out a spark,_ etc.